# Is it possible to schedule a Sandbox refresh programmatically?

Tags: apex

Strictly speaking, refreshing sandboxes via the Salesforce application isn't 'dynamic' as one needs to manually refresh the sandbox(es).

I know that [this Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000knljAAA) is currently open, but I wonder if it is possible to refresh a sandbox programmatically in Salesforce? Using Workbench, I am not able to report on sandboxes as an sObject, so I am under the impression that I cannot achieve this via a cron job?